# Salesforce SOAP API Referencement on Google

Tags: discussion

When I search for some Salesforce objects definitions in Google, I often get the Japanese result.

Am I the only one with this problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not really a Meta question, but also has been asked on the main exchange: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176031/2995

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson. Sorry, could it be possible to move it to the main exchange? Yes I saw this previous problem too with the related question. But the referencement was already corrected :( I think the japanese version is a new problem.